# How to add data to an array in JavaScript and display data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push my data from input filed to an array and then display it in li. But only i can achieve is array in console. my for loop is ok?

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn-sub');
btn.addEventListener('click', addToDo);

function addToDo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let value = document.getElementById('field').value;
  let values = [];
  values.push(value);
  for (var index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    var element = values[index];
    let li = document.getElementsByClassName('collection-item');
    li.innerText += element;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s10">
      <input id="field" type="text" class="validate">

      <label for="password">To do!</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btn-sub">button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The array `values` only has on item being added to it, therefore the loop runs only once. What is happening when you run it? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: first problem I see if you are setting `let values = [];` to an empty array each time you `addToDo()`

Comment: What do you wish to achieve by having an array? I can tell you why you don't get anything in the `li`

Comment: @VTodorov i want to be able to delete added items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `document.getElementsByClassName('collection-item')`, it returns an array of nodes, and you have to select, which item from this array you want to use. So in your case it should be `let li = document.getElementsByClassName('collection-item')[index]`, for example `document.getElementsByClassName('collection-item')[0]` will select the first item from all nodes. Here is the working example (without refactoring your code):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn-sub');

btn.addEventListener('click', addToDo);
function addToDo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let value = document.getElementById('field').value;
  let values = [];
  values.push(value);
  for (var index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    var element = values[index];
    let li = document.getElementsByClassName('collection-item')[index];
    li.innerText += element;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10">
            <input id="field" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="password">To do!</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btn-sub">button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item">
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Update

*"ok, how to make this work when i want to have each time new li with new data from input field? not overwrite previous li"*

I simplified the code a little, you don't really need the array and the loop in this case, because you have only one input:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn-sub');

btn.addEventListener('click', addToDo);
function addToDo() {
  let value = document.getElementById('field').value;
  let node = document.createElement("LI")
  document.getElementsByClassName('collection')[0].appendChild(node).innerText = value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s10">
            <input id="field" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="password">To do!</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btn-sub">button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="collection"></ul>
```

Feel free to ask, if anything isn't clear.

Comment: ok, how to make this work when i want to have each time new li with new data from input field? not overwrite previous li

Comment: @Damian, I have updated the answer with what you asked for

Comment: i want to set up an Array to be able to delete added items. or how to iterate without a loop?

Comment: @Damian, it's the right way, if you work with multiple values, in your case looping through array would be the best approach. I simplified the code just because in provided example you have only one input and adding only one value

Comment: ok could you provide me ode where i am adding data to array insted of just creating ne li and puting data in it?

Comment: @Damian, if I understood you correctly, it's already in the first part of my answer. Is it what are you asking for?

Comment: in the first part when you tpye a new value into input field it is not creating new li but updating exsisitng li and it value insted of creating new li with new value each time as second code is doing

Comment: @Damian, you want to add one more `li` with input's value inside this `li` on every button click and keep all previous values in array?